# PyQt5 QSortFilterProxyModel Sort Column by appropriate data type (int, float, datetime, string, etc)

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, pyqt5

I wrap a QAbstractTableModel instance in a QSortFilterProxyModel in order to be able to sort and filter it.  Sort requests sort column data as strings - instead I want the columns to be sortable by their appropriate datatype.

There are a handful of questions/answers on the site that speak roughly about this problem, but none provide a contained solution to the 'sort appropriate data type' problem for a table where the need is to be able to sort any column by the method appropriate for its datatype.

By appropriate sort method, I mean I want the QSortFilterProxyModel to sort integer columns as integers, sort float columns as floats, sort date columns as dates, and sort string columns as strings (well, the string kind, it already handles...).

There seem to be one or two ways suggested to accomplish this.  One involves setting up your source model to have its own SortRole that, for example, sort a column by integers.  Can that implementation be tweaked to sort a column by it's 'native' datatype rather than pre-prescribing a SortRole for each column?

In my specific use case, the source model is actually a pandas dataframe model.  This is worth noting because perhaps conveniently, each of my columns DOES have a native/built-in/reliable datatype that could be known progammatically.  Hence if it made implementation easier, I would forego the ability to sort a single column with many different datatypes*, to receive the ability to sort by any column by the correct method for its datatype.  (*I realize there are cases where that ability is useful and appreciate that is perhaps what the default behavior agnostically addresses, but I have no immediate need for it.)

Another solution I've seen discussed either by itself or in conjunction with special roles, involves reimplementing the QSortFilterProxyModel class and overloading the lessThan function.  This solution makes sense to me, I just haven't been able to find an example where a clean implementation of this is done that can apply the appropriate sort method for the data based on the datatype of data it's sorting.  Those solutions all seem to rely on a hardcoding a method for a column.  It seems like there should be away to handle that 'column-sort method' lookup programmatically either on the fly as the lessThan method is called, or at least each time the sourcemodel refreshes.

See end of post for the minimal reproducible example.

Or see these snippets:

```
class App(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    # responsible for instantiating the view, controllers, and model(s) 
    # and passing references between them.
    
    def __init__(self, sys_argv):
        super(App, self).__init__(sys_argv)
        
        self.ticks_model = TicksModel()
        self.proxy_ticks_model=QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxy_ticks_model.setSourceModel(self.ticks_model)

        self.depth_model=DepthModel()
        self.depth_model_harem=DepthModelHarem()
        
        self.sc_model=ScModel()
        self.main_controller = MainController(self.ticks_model,
                                              self.proxy_ticks_model, self.depth_model,
                                              self.depth_model_harem,self.sc_model)
        
        self.main_view = MainView(self.ticks_model, 
                                  self.proxy_ticks_model, self.depth_model,
                                  self.depth_model_harem, self.sc_model,
                                  self.main_controller)
        
        self.main_view.show()
```

```
class DataFrameModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    DtypeRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000
    ValueRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1001
    # ColumnHasNumbersRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1002
# bunch of other methods
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        # dt stands for data type here
        if not index.isValid() or not (0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount() \
            and 0 <= index.column() < self.columnCount()):
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        row = self._dataframe.index[index.row()]
        col = self._dataframe.columns[index.column()]
        dt = self._dataframe[col].dtype

        val = self._dataframe.iloc[row][col]
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(val)
        elif role == DataFrameModel.ValueRole:
            return val
        if role == DataFrameModel.DtypeRole:
            return dt

        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if val == 'Sell':
                return QtGui.QColor('red')
            elif val == 'Buy':
                return QtGui.QColor('blue')
            
        return QtCore.QVariant()
```

```
class TicksModel(DataFrameModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TicksModel, self).__init__()
    def setDataFrame(self):
        self.beginResetModel()
        df=get_df()
        self._dataframe = df.copy()
        self.endResetModel()
```

@eyllanesc here is a minimal reproducible example

```
import logging 
__log__=logging.getLogger()
import sys 
import pandas as pd 

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QComboBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, QDate, QTime, QSortFilterProxyModel

def get_df():
    return pd.DataFrame([{'int':-1,'str':'foo'},
            {'int':0,'str':'bar'},
            {'int':1, 'str':'abc'},
            {'int':10,'str':'abc'},
            {'int':101, 'str':'def'},
            {'int':2,'str':'def'}])
    

class DataFrameModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    DtypeRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000
    ValueRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1001
    ColumnHasNumbersRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1002

    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        super(DataFrameModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._dataframe = df
        
    def dataFrame(self):
        return self._dataframe

    def setDataFrame(self):
        # i tend to overload this in child classes with the data getting
        return 
    # this seems to be some kind of after the fact decorator?? ask
    dataFrame = QtCore.pyqtProperty(pd.DataFrame, fget=dataFrame, fset=setDataFrame)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, QtCore.Qt.Orientation, result=str)
    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: QtCore.Qt.Orientation,
                   role: int = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return self._dataframe.columns[section]
            else:
                return str(self._dataframe.index[section])
        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return len(self._dataframe.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return self._dataframe.columns.size

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        # dt stands for data type here
        if not index.isValid() or not (0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount() \
            and 0 <= index.column() < self.columnCount()):
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        row = self._dataframe.index[index.row()]
        col = self._dataframe.columns[index.column()]
        dt = self._dataframe[col].dtype

        val = self._dataframe.iloc[row][col]
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(val)
        elif role == DataFrameModel.ValueRole:
            return val
        if role == DataFrameModel.DtypeRole:
            return dt

        if role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if val == 'Sell':
                return QtGui.QColor('red')
            elif val == 'Buy':
                return QtGui.QColor('blue')
            
        return QtCore.QVariant()
    
    def roleNames(self):
        roles = {QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole: b'display',
            DataFrameModel.DtypeRole: b'dtype',
            DataFrameModel.ValueRole: b'value'}
        return roles
    
    def signalUpdate(self):
        ''' tell viewers to update their data 
        (this is full update, not efficient)'''
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
    
    def sort(self, Ncol, order):
        """Sort table by given column number."""
        try:
            self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
            self._dataframe = self._dataframe.sort_values(self._dataframe.columns[Ncol], ascending=not order).reset_index(drop=True)
            self.layoutChanged.emit()
        except Exception as e:
            __log__.error(e)
            
class TicksModel(DataFrameModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TicksModel, self).__init__()
    def setDataFrame(self):
        self.beginResetModel()
        df=get_df()
        self._dataframe = df.copy()
        self.endResetModel()
        
class App(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    # responsible for instantiating the view, controllers, and model(s) 
    # and passing references between them.
    
    def __init__(self, sys_argv):
        super(App, self).__init__(sys_argv)
        
        self.ticks_model = TicksModel()
        self.proxy_ticks_model=QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxy_ticks_model.setSourceModel(self.ticks_model)

        self.main_controller = MainController(self.ticks_model,
                                              self.proxy_ticks_model)
        
        self.main_view = MainView(self.ticks_model, 
                                  self.proxy_ticks_model, self.main_controller)
        
        self.main_view.show()
        

class MainController(QObject):
    # perform logic, set data in model
    
    def __init__(self, ticks_model, proxy_ticks_model, 
                 ):
        super().__init__()

        self._ticks_model = ticks_model
        self._proxy_ticks_model=proxy_ticks_model
        self.refresh_ticks_df()
        
    @pyqtSlot()
    def refresh_ticks_df(self):
        # methods here can be called from the view,
        # accept value as arguments from the widgets, say, performs logic, and sets attributes on the model.
        self._ticks_model.setDataFrame()
        
    @pyqtSlot()
    def setFilterRegExp(self, search):
        self._proxy_ticks_model.setFilterRegExp(search)
        
    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def setFilterKeyColumn(self, index):
        self._proxy_ticks_model.setFilterKeyColumn(index)

class MainView(QMainWindow):

# contain the minimal code required to connect to the signals coming from the widgets in your layout. 
# View events can call and pass basic information to a method in the view class and onto a method in a controller class,
# where any logic should be. It would look something like:

    def __init__(self, ticks_model, 
                 proxy_ticks_model, main_controller):
        super().__init__()
        self._ticks_model=ticks_model
        self._proxy_ticks_model = proxy_ticks_model
        self._main_controller = main_controller
        
        # import the relevant auto-generated classes from the .py layout files.
        self._ui = Ui_blackbird()
        self._ui.setupUi(self)

        # its possible thsi should go somewhere else, but thinking this makes sense
        # as its about the UI really
        self._ui.tableView.setModel(self._proxy_ticks_model)
        self._ui.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self._ui.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self._ui.comboBox.addItems(["{0}".format(col) for col in 
                                    self._ticks_model._dataframe.columns])

        # connect widgets to controller        
        self._ui.lineEdit_3.returnPressed.connect(self.on_lineEdit_textChanged)
        self._ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.on_lineEdit_textChanged)

        self._ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self._main_controller.refresh_ticks_df)
        
        
    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_lineEdit_textChanged(self):
        text=self._ui.lineEdit_3.text().strip()
        search = QtCore.QRegExp(    text,
                                    QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive,
                                    QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp
                                    )

        self._main_controller.setFilterRegExp(search)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(self, index):
        self._main_controller.setFilterKeyColumn(index)
        

class Ui_blackbird(object):
    def setupUi(self, blackbird):
        blackbird.setObjectName("blackbird")
        blackbird.resize(920, 586)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(blackbird.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        blackbird.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(blackbird)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tabWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tabWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tab_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tab_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.tab_3)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab_3)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableView.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tableView.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tableView.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.tableView.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.tableView.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tableView.setObjectName("tableView")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableView, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.tab_3)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.comboBox, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 7)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4, 1, 4, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab_4)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_4)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.dateTimeEdit = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(self.tab_4)
        self.dateTimeEdit.setObjectName("dateTimeEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.dateTimeEdit)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_4)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.tableView_2 = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab_4)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableView_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tableView_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.tableView_2.setFont(font)
        self.tableView_2.setLineWidth(0)
        self.tableView_2.setObjectName("tableView_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView_2)
        self.tableView_4 = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab_4)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableView_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tableView_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.tableView_4.setFont(font)
        self.tableView_4.setLineWidth(0)
        self.tableView_4.setObjectName("tableView_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView_4)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.tab_13 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_13.setObjectName("tab_13")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab_13)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_13)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.tab_13)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.tableView_3 = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab_13)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tableView_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tableView_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tableView_3.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.tableView_3.setObjectName("tableView_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableView_3)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_13, "")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.SpanningRole, self.tabWidget)
        blackbird.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(blackbird)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        blackbird.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(blackbird)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(blackbird)

    def retranslateUi(self, blackbird):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        blackbird.setWindowTitle(_translate("blackbird", "Blackbird"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("blackbird", "Actions"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("blackbird", "Regex:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("blackbird", "refresh"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("blackbird", "Regex Filter Column: "))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("blackbird", "Push Me or just Hit Enter Regex Filter"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("blackbird", "Ticks"))
        self.dateTimeEdit.setDisplayFormat(_translate("blackbird", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AP"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("blackbird", "Load"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("blackbird", ""))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("blackbird", "Load"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_13), _translate("blackbird", ""))


        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig()
    app = App(sys.argv)
    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except Exception as e:
        __log__.error('%s', e)
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc , posted.  thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simplistic solution:
Call the data method in the source model (that inherits from QAbstractTableModel) from the reimplemented QSortFilterProxyModel 's lessThan method , passing a role argument that will expose values to the lessThan method rather than strings.  Then the natural < operator sort 'just works', because it's sorting values ... (as long as the values are comparable (I added some None handling etc to avoid crashes on non-comparable data)).

So the reimplemented QSortFilterProxyModel could look like this:

```
class DataframeQSortFilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DataframeQSortFilterProxyModel, self).__init__()
        self.role=DataFrameModel.ValueRole
        
    def lessThan(self, left, right):
        role=self.role
        leftData=self.sourceModel().data(left, role)
        rightData=self.sourceModel().data(right, role)
        if leftData is None:
            return True
        elif rightData is None:
            return False
        elif type(leftData) != type(rightData): 
            # don't want to sort at all in these cases, False is just a copout ...
            # should warn user
            return False
        return leftData < rightData
```

where the data method in the source model looks similar to before, like this:

```
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        # dt stands for data type here
        if not index.isValid() or not (0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount() \
            and 0 <= index.column() < self.columnCount()):
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        row = self._dataframe.index[index.row()]
        col = self._dataframe.columns[index.column()]
        dt = self._dataframe[col].dtype

        val = self._dataframe.iloc[row][col]
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(val)
        elif role == DataFrameModel.ValueRole:
            return val
        elif role == DataFrameModel.DtypeRole:
            return dt
        elif role == QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole:
            if val == 'Sell':
                return QtGui.QColor('red')
            elif val == 'Buy':
                return QtGui.QColor('blue')
            
        return QtCore.QVariant()
```